# How to capture a variable of this object in lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I have seen many answers on SO asking about capturing `this` by reference but I have a different question. What if I want to capture a specific variable owned by `this` object?

For example:

```
auto rel_pose = [this->_last_pose["main_pose"],&pose](Eigen::VectorXd pose1, Eigen::VectorXd pose2)
    {
        // Some code
        return pose;
    };
```

I want to capture the specific variable of `this` by value and use it inside my lambda expression. Why this is not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply [by-copy capture with an initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) (since C++14) (or by-reference capture with an initializer, depends on your demand), e.g.

```
auto rel_pose = [some_pose = this->_last_pose["main_pose"], &pose](Eigen::VectorXd pose1, Eigen::VectorXd pose2)
{
    // Some code using some_pose
    return pose;
};
```

Note that we can only [capture](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) identifiers in lambda, we can't capture expressions like `this->_last_pose["main_pose"]` directly. The *captures with an initializer* just solve such issues straightforward.

Comment: Why is that we need to copy the object's variable in order to capture it? Just a C++ rule?

Comment: @Edmund We don't need to copy it. We can use references.

Comment: @Edmund ??? You said "want to capture the specific variable of this by value".. You can capture by reference too.

Comment: @songyuanyao I mean the assignment operation, what does it represent in the capture brackets?

Comment: @L.F. I think you misunderstood me, I didn't mean ```[&the_pose = this->_last_pose["main_pose"], &pose]```, I was asking why can't we just pass the object's variable without the assignment operation

Comment: @Edmund It's used for the initializer list; this is initialization, not assignment. (So it's not the assignment operator.)

Comment: @songyuanyao So whenever we want to pass some object's variable in lambda we need to initialize a new variable for that?

Comment: @Edmund Yes. And I think I get what you meant, we can only [capture](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) *identifier* in lambda, we can't capture expressions like `this->_last_pose["main_pose"]` directly. And *capture with an initializer* could solve such issues.

Comment: @Edmund *So whenever we want to pass some object's variable in lambda we need to initialize a new variable for that* How would the alternative even work? What you specify in the example is more than "an object's variable", it's a whole expression that involves the object. You can't just put that in the capture and somehow expect the body of the lambda to *recognize* the same arbitrary expression when found in the lambda body, and automatically transform it into the captured reference. Especially as especially as arbitrary expressions can differ in subtle ways.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible:

```
struct S
{
    int i = 7;
    char c = 0;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    S s;
    auto l = [integer = s.i]() {
        return integer;
    };

    return l();
}
```

Comment: Why is that we need to copy the object's variable in order to capture it? Just a C++ rule?

Answer (score 0):

> Why this is not possible?

It's possible, like other answers show. But you must do it *explicitly*. Accessing any member of the current object in the lambda is transformed automatically to an access through the `this` pointer. When you write a plain `[this->_last_pose["main_pose"],&pose]`, what's really captured is `this`, and the access to `_last_pose` goes through it.

It's simply how lambda captures are specified for member variables. Be grateful you are compiling C++14. In C++11 capturing members by value was not as easy as adding an init capture that does an copy.